# OSX Style dock in Ajax

Tags: css, ajax

I am building a new site for a client and they want and OSX style dock at the foot of the page.

Any ideas or examples of how to get started with this.

I guess Ajax would be the best option.

Freja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

http://www.addthis.com/gallery/share-dock

There is a a clear html code example and the accompanying CSS / JS.